# How do i view the schemas in PL/SQL developer?

Tags: oracle, schema, plsqldeveloper

I want to view the Schemas that belong to a database in PL/SQL Developer.

I know that in SQL Developer I can view them in the "Other users" node, but where are the schemas in PL/SQL Developer?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your access level.

In Oracle "Users" own objects, so users and schemas are often used synonymously.

You can see the users by querying `ALL_USERS` (or `DBA_USERS` if you have DBA access).

If you define "schema" as a user that owns objects, you can query `ALL_OBJECTS` ( or `DBA_OBJECTS` ):

```
SELECT owner, count(1) num_objs 
FROM all_objects 
GROUP BY owner;
```

To get a list of objects for a particular user/schema:

```
SELECT object_type, object_name 
FROM all_objects 
WHERE owner = 'FRED' 
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```